# How to hang electric fence from posts?

Tags: pipe, fence, rebar

I need to make some posts for a small electric fence (designed for small animals / gardens) in my backyard. This just encloses my vegetable garden to keep out rabbits. My wire is aluminum.

I want to use rebar and/or PVC plastic conduit (the grey electrical variety) for the posts, but I don't know what to use to hang the aluminum wire. I need to run 3 stands of wire approx. 3" apart at heights of 5", 8" & 11" off the ground.

Some type of plastic hook that could wrap around the conduit or rebar would be ideal. If using just rebar, the aluminum wire would have to hang away from the rebar without touching it.

I've looked at some different types of pipe clamps but haven't found anything suitable yet. It would be great if I could move these clamps / hooks up and down the posts to adjust the height of the wires from time to time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have access to mail order the purpose made electric fence wire hangers? There are cheap commercially available, purpose made devices for this.

Comment: Yes, I could mail order them. Do you mean something like these: http://www.acehardware.com/product/index.jsp?productId=25115396 http://www.acehardware.com/product/index.jsp?productId=25115446

Comment: Precisely. I find that you can rarely beat something purpose made, designed and tested for your application. Depending on your location, many "farm and feed" type stores may even have them on the shelf if you want to save on shipping.

Comment: OK, thanks ... strangely I didn't even think of this ... I guess I was too much in the DIY mode. =) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Purpose-made hangers are probably best, but here's a DIY idea. At this low height, PVC conduit or pipe could work. Simply drill through the pipe and thread the wire through.

Comment: A quick search yields many options for hanging electric fencing wire. https://afence.com/store/Round-Post-and-ReBar-Insulators/

Answer (score 4):

You could cut a notch (like 1/4 pipe depth) in the pipe and just wrap the wire around the pipe, tucking it into the notch.

[image]

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution. Thanks.

Comment: Or run the wire through continuous, and use a bit of lighter wire to do the binding, e.g. 14AWG or 1.0mm solid. (Not calling those equivalent, just examples of readily available wire.). Great answer Ben.

Answer (score 1):

Your local farm supply will have fiberglass stakes and spring clip insulators for this. For rabbits, the stakes may be too long at 4' so cut them in half to double your stake count.

Comment: Awesome, that's a much better solution than rebar. How do you suggest cutting the fiberglass stakes? I don't have any tools and will need to buy some kind of simple tool to cut them.

Comment: A hacksaw probably would be best, it's a basic tool that can be used for metal, plastic and some wood work. Using a wood saw, the fiberglass is a bit rough on the teeth.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how sturdy the fence needs to be you could cut the plastic conduit to a point and hammer it into the ground. Then use plastic wire ties to secure the fence wire to the plastic pipe. If you used two ties in an "X" it would hold the wire in place but still slide up and down if adjustment is needed. If you need a sturdier fence you could put smaller metal conduit in as posts then slip plastic conduit over it as an insulator.

Comment: Thank you. This tip will come in handy in other contexts.